# Mutate observed property in KVO observeValueForKeyPath

Tags: objective-c, key-value-observing

I have a view controller with a `NSMutableArray` property observed by KVO :

```
@interface MyViewController ()

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *values;

@end

@implementation MyViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.values = [NSMutableArray array];

    [self addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"self.values" options:0 context:nil];
}

- (void)dealloc
{
    [self removeObserver:self forKeyPath:@"self.values"];
}

- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context
{
    if ([keyPath isEqualToString:@"self.values"])
    {
        // The code here is a bit more complex than that, but the main idea
        // is to mutate the object
        [self.values addObject:[NSDate date]]; // This line triggers a KVO notification, causing an infinite recursion 
    }
}

@end
```

The goal of my implementation is to apply discounts on each product in the array, and recalculate theses discouts each time a product is added to the array.

I'd like to modify the observed property when a notification is received, but obviously the code above do not work, it goes into infinite recursion.

One solution would be to remove the observer at the beginning of `observeValueForKeyPath...` and re-add the observer at the end.

This seems a bit ugly though, and may cause problems is the property is modified on one thread while `observeValueForKeyPath...` is running on another.

**EDIT**: As Wain pointed out, the real problem here is that my `NSMutableArray` `self.value` could contain immutable object (`NSDictionnary`s) and I have no way to replace them by their mutable equivalent with something like:

```
[self.value replaceObjectAtIndex:0 withObject:[self.value[0] mutableCopy]];
```

without triggering the KVO notification.

Comment: So why do you need to mutate the array? Your requirements sound like you just need to iterate the array and mutate other state or the state of the objects in the array...

Comment: You are absolutely right, I guess my real problem is that the `NSMutableArray` contains `NSDictionnary`s and as they are immutable, I'm using `replaceObjectAtIndex:withObject:` on my `NSMutableArray`. Thanks for the eye opening. So if I mutate objects in my array, it won't trigger the notification ?

Comment: It shouldn't (as far as I know / remember) because KVO doesn't do any kind of depth search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you value your time, don't add or remove KVO observations during calls to `observeValueForKeyPath:...`. For details, go read my answer to [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17097311/locking-exposuremode-with-key-value-observer-causes-crash).

If you really need to do this, you can add an ivar that serves as a flag to stop the recursion. It might look something like this:

```
@interface MyViewController ()

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *values;

@end

@implementation MyViewController
{
    BOOL _updatingValuesInObservation;
}

static void * const MyValueObservation = (void*)&MyValueObservation;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.values = [NSMutableArray array];

    [self addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"values" options:0 context:MyValueObservation];
}

- (void)dealloc
{
    [self removeObserver:self forKeyPath:@"values" context:MyValueObservation];
}

- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context
{
    if (MyValueObservation == context && !_updatingValuesInObservation)
    {
        _updatingValuesInObservation = YES;
        [self.values addObject:[NSDate date]];
        _updatingValuesInObservation = NO; 
    }
    else
    {
        [super observeValueForKeyPath:keyPath ofObject:object change:change context:context];
    }
}

@end
```

Also note the use of the context parameter and the calling of super, both good habits to be in for more bullet-proof code.

Lastly, you're not doing this here, but it seems like you're on the path, so I'll mention it: Remember that observing a collection is not the same as observing all the items *in* a collection.

Comment: I rewrote my code without KVO after all, mainly because of the "not observing *items* in the collection" thing, but your solution is quite elegant. Thanks for the tips, I'll rewrite my `observeValueForKeyPath:` methods to use `context`.