# What's a good way to make a one-shot KVO observation?

Tags: key-value-observing

I want to add a KVO observation that removes itself after it fires once. I have seen lots of folks on StackOverflow doing stuff like this:

```
- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context
{
    if ([keyPath isEqualToString:@"myKeyPath"])
    {
        NSLog(@"Do stuff...");
        [object removeObserver:self forKeyPath:@"isFinished"];
    }
    else
    {
        [super observeValueForKeyPath:keyPath ofObject:object change:change context:context];
    }
}
```

This seems plausible, but I'm aware that calling `-removeObserver:forKeyPath:` from within `-observeValueForKeyPath:...` [can be lead to non-deterministic crashes that are hard to debug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17097311/locking-exposuremode-with-key-value-observer-causes-crash/17148365#17148365). I also want to be sure this observation only gets called once (or not at all if the notification is never sent). What's a good way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm answering my own question here because I've seen the pattern in the question all over the place,  but haven't had a reference to a good example of a better way. I've lost days, if not weeks, of my life to debugging problems ultimately found to be caused by adding and removing observers during the delivery of KVO notifications. Without warranty, I present the following implementation of a one-shot KVO notification that should avoid the problems that come from calling `-addObserver:...` and `-removeObserver:...` from inside `-observeValueForKeyPath:...`. The code:

**NSObject+KVOOneShot.h:**

```
typedef void (^KVOOneShotObserverBlock)(NSString* keyPath, id object, NSDictionary* change, void* context);

@interface NSObject (KVOOneShot)

- (void)addKVOOneShotObserverForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath options:(NSKeyValueObservingOptions)options context:(void *)context block: (KVOOneShotObserverBlock)block;

@end
```

**NSObject+KVOOneShot.m:** (Compile with -fno-objc-arc so we can be explicit about retain/releases)

```
#import "NSObject+KVOOneShot.h"
#import <libkern/OSAtomic.h>
#import <objc/runtime.h>

@interface KVOOneShotObserver : NSObject
- (instancetype)initWithBlock: (KVOOneShotObserverBlock)block;
@end

@implementation NSObject (KVOOneShot)

- (void)addKVOOneShotObserverForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath options:(NSKeyValueObservingOptions)options context:(void *)context block: (KVOOneShotObserverBlock)block
{
    if (!block || !keyPath)
        return;

    KVOOneShotObserver* observer = nil;
    @try
    {
        observer = [[KVOOneShotObserver alloc] initWithBlock: block];
        // Tie the observer's lifetime to the object it's observing...
        objc_setAssociatedObject(self, observer, observer, OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN);
        // Add the observation...
        [self addObserver: observer forKeyPath: keyPath options: options context: context];
    }
    @finally
    {
        // Make sure we release our hold on the observer, even if something goes wrong above. Probably paranoid of me.
        [observer release];
    }
}

@end

@implementation KVOOneShotObserver
{
   void * volatile _block;
}

- (instancetype)initWithBlock: (KVOOneShotObserverBlock)block
{
    if (self = [super init])
    {
        _block = [block copy];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)dealloc
{
    [(id)_block release];
    [super dealloc];
}

- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context
{
    KVOOneShotObserverBlock block = (KVOOneShotObserverBlock)_block;

    // Get the block atomically, so it can only ever be executed once.
    if (block && OSAtomicCompareAndSwapPtrBarrier(block, NULL, &self->_block))
    {
        // Do it.
        @try
        {
            block(keyPath, object, change, context);
        }
        @finally
        {
            // Release it.
            [block release];

            // Remove the observation whenever...
            // Note: This can potentially extend the lifetime of the observer until the observation is removed.
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                [object removeObserver: self forKeyPath: keyPath context: context];
            });

            // Don't keep us alive any longer than necessary...
            objc_setAssociatedObject(object, self, nil, OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN);
        }
    }
}

@end
```

The only potential hitch here is that the `dispatch_async` deferred removal may marginally extend the lifetime of the observed object by one pass of the main run loop. This shouldn't be a big deal in the common case, but it's worth mentioning. My initial thought was to remove the observation in `dealloc`, but my understanding is that we don't have a strong guarantee that the observed object will still be alive when the `-dealloc` of `KVOOneShotObserver` is called. Logically, that should be the case, since the observed object will have the only "seen" retain, but since we pass this object into API whose implementation we can't see, we can't be completely sure.  Given that, this feels like the safest way.

Comment: What's the purpose of the try-finally blocks? Can't the same functionality be obtained without them?

Comment: The `@try/@finally` block in `-addKVOOneShotObserverForKeyPath:` guards against an exception being thrown in `-addObserver:...` or `objc_setAssociatedObject`. If you believed that `objc_setAssociatedObject` can't throw, then arguably yes, you could get rid of this one. The `@try/@finally` in `-observeValueForKeyPath:` is *much* more important in that it guards against exceptions thrown in `block(...)` which would prevent the observation from being removed and would cause `block` (and anything in it's lexical closure) to be leaked, even if the exception were caught by the calling code.

Comment: If you take the standard Cocoa mindset that any exception thrown equals death, then sure they're pointless, but then so is every @try ever. FWIW, Cocoa Bindings, which are built on top of KVO, routinely throw and swallow exceptions, so it hardly seems safe to ignore the possibility.