# Manual KVO notification causes crash in serial queue

Tags: ios, objective-c, asynchronous, grand-central-dispatch, key-value-observing

I'm experiencing a rather odd crash relating to manual KVO notification on a particular property of my data manager class.

This class loads its data asynchronously on a custom serial queue. After loading is finished, the class sets it's property `dataLoaded` to the appropriate value depending on whether data was loaded successfully or not. Observers can observe this property in order to be notified when loading has completed.

Under normal circumstances, this works perfectly fine. The problem arises when I allow the data loading to be canceled, which returns early from the loading block, sets `isDataLoaded` to NO and `wasLoadingCanceled` to YES. Here is a video demonstrating the issue: 
[Demo video](https://www.dropbox.com/s/hj22q0mdyeyzrci/async.mov?dl=0)

As can be seen in the video, the exception always occurs on the line:

```
[self willChangeValueForKey:...];
```

Here are the relevant methods for the `DataManager` class:

```
// .h
@property (nonatomic, readonly) BOOL dataLoaded;
@property (nonatomic, readonly, getter=isDataLoading) BOOL dataLoading;
@property (nonatomic, readonly, getter=wasLoadingCanceled) BOOL loadingCanceled;

// .m
- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        _data = @[];
        _dataLoaded = NO;
        _dataLoading = NO;
        _loadingCanceled = NO;
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)_clearData:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    if (self.isDataLoading) {
        _loadingCanceled = YES;
    } else {
        self.dataLoaded = NO;
    }

    _data = @[];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:@"WillLogOut" object:nil];
}

- (void)loadDataWithBlock:(NSArray* (^)(void))block
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(_clearData:) name:@"WillLogOut" object:nil];

    dispatch_queue_t loadingQueue = dispatch_queue_create("com.LoadingQueue", NULL);

    __weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self;
    dispatch_async(loadingQueue, ^{
        __strong typeof(weakSelf) strongSelf = weakSelf;

        strongSelf->_dataLoading = YES;
        strongSelf->_loadingCanceled = NO;

        NSLog(@"Data loading...");
        strongSelf.data = block();
        strongSelf->_dataLoading = NO;
        NSLog(@"Data loaded.");

        BOOL dataLoaded = (strongSelf.data != nil);
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            // CRASH here now...
            strongSelf.dataLoaded = dataLoaded;
        });
    });
}

//- (void)setDataLoaded:(BOOL)dataLoaded
//{
// CRASH: Exception always on the following line:
//    [self willChangeValueForKey:NSStringFromSelector(@selector(isDataLoaded))];
//    _dataLoaded = dataLoaded;
//    [self didChangeValueForKey:NSStringFromSelector(@selector(isDataLoaded))];
//}
```

Here is the code that starts the loading when logging in:

```
[dataManager loadDataWithBlock:^NSArray *{
        NSMutableArray *data = [NSMutableArray array];
        [data addObject:@"One"];
        [data addObject:@"Two"];
        // NOTE: Simulating longer loading time.
        usleep(1.0 * 1.0e6);

        if (dataManager.wasLoadingCanceled) {
            NSLog(@"Loading canceled.");
            return nil;
        }

        [data addObject:@"Three"];
        [data addObject:@"Four"];
        [data addObject:@"Five"];
        // NOTE: Simulating longer loading time.
        usleep(1.0 * 1.0e6);

        if (dataManager.wasLoadingCanceled) {
            NSLog(@"Loading canceled.");
            return nil;
        }

        [data addObject:@"Six"];
        [data addObject:@"Seven"];

        return data;
    }];
```

And finally, here is the code for the observing view controller that populates the table view:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    if (self.dataManager.dataLoaded) {
        [self.dataTable reloadData];
    } else {
        [self.dataManager addObserver:self
                           forKeyPath:NSStringFromSelector(@selector(dataLoaded))
                              options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew
                              context:nil];
    }
}

- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context
{
    if ([keyPath isEqualToString:NSStringFromSelector(@selector(dataLoaded))]) {
        BOOL check = [[change objectForKey:NSKeyValueChangeNewKey] boolValue];
        if (check) {
            dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                [self.dataTable reloadSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:0] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            });

            [self.dataManager removeObserver:self forKeyPath:NSStringFromSelector(@selector(dataLoaded)) context:nil];
        }
    }
}

- (IBAction)logOut:(id)sender
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"WillLogOut" object:self userInfo:nil];
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

And yes, I did try to dispatch the manual KVO notification to the main thread, but that results in a complete lock in the UI.

EDIT: I changed the `dataLoaded` property to not use a different getter, removing the need for manual KVO. However, there is still a crash now when trying to set the property.

Here is the stack trace:
[image: Stack trace]

Comment: Can you please post the stack trace?

Comment: Also: does the behavior change if you redeclare the properties as `readwrite` in the `.m` file and just call `self.dataLoaded = dataLoaded;`?

Comment: @AaronBrager I posted the stack trace. And no, the behavior didn't change if I declare the property `readwrite` in the .m file.

Comment: It looks like you are trying to make a one-shot KVO observation. The way you're doing it here has some pitfalls. This might be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18210461

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The name of your property is `dataLoaded`. Therefore, the key you use with KVC and KVO should be `@"dataLoaded"`, not `@"isDataLoaded"`. `isDataLoaded` is just the name of a getter, not the property. Consider, for example, if the property were publicly read-write (I know it's not), would you think that `[object setValue:newValue forKey:@"isDataLoaded"]` to be correct? That would look for a setter named `-setIsDataLoaded:`, which doesn't exist.

If you fix that, then there's no need to manually post KVO change notifications. Any call to `-setDataLoaded:` is going to generate them automatically (assuming you haven't disabled that by overriding `+automaticallyNotifiesObserversForKey:`).

Likewise, things like `self.dataManager.isDataLoaded` are kind of wrong. With dot syntax, you should use the property name, not the getter name. The *declared* property is named `dataLoaded`. It produces a getter named `-isDataLoaded`. It happens that the existence of a getter implies the existence of an *informal* property with the getter's name. So, the declared property `dataLoaded` happens to imply the existence of an informal property named `isDataLoaded` — which is why your code compiles — but that's not really the name of your class's property.

I'm not sure why you're using the construct `NSStringFromSelector(@selector(isDataLoaded))`, but I think it would just be better to use a symbolic string constant.

Dispatching the setting of the property to the main thread could probably be made to work, but you would want to do it asynchronously, not synchronously as your commented-out code shows. Also, if the KVO change notification is posted on the main thread, then your `-observeValueForKeyPath:...` method **must not** use `dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ...)` because that will definitely deadlock. Either execute that code directly or dispatch it asynchronously.

Beyond that, we'd need to see crash details to give a more narrowly-focused answer.

Comment: Yeah, it still seemed to work though, even using the @"isDataLoaded", but I see what you're saying. The odd thing is, it works fine unless I cancel the loading. That's the only time it crashes, and all it does is return early from the loading block setting `data` to nil.

Comment: Also, yes, I fixed the deadlock that occured when dispatching to the main thread in the `-observeValueForKeyPath:...` method. Thanks for catching that.

Comment: I did not mean to suggest that you shouldn't use `getter=isDataLoaded` if you want. It's just that when you use KVC, KVO, or dot syntax, you use the property name, not the getter name. The crash looks like an observer has been deallocated. Try specifying a real, unique context when calling `-addObserver:forKeyPath:...` and checking it in `-observeValueForKeyPath:...`. If it's not yours, call through to super and return. It's possible that the framework is using KVO on your object and you're interfering with it by not doing that.

Comment: By the way, you don't need to do the `weakSelf` dance in `-loadDataWithBlock:`. It doesn't keep strong references to the blocks it creates — it just submits them to GCD, which will release them after running them — so there's no chance of a retain cycle.

Comment: Yep, it was indeed a problem with the observer. I added a call to `-removeObserver:...` in `viewDidDisappear:` in the case where loading was canceled and that seems to have done it. Thanks for the help.

Comment: FWIW, `NSStringFromSelector(@selector())` is one way to get *some* semblance of compile time checking for key paths. It's nowhere near as good as EXTKeyPathCoding, but it's better than nothing. (For reference: https://github.com/jspahrsummers/libextobjc )

Comment: I figured, but it seems pretty weak to me. As we've been discussing, property names and selector names aren't the same thing. A symbol string constant still has potential for error at its definition site, but is otherwise safe and seems much simpler. To each his or her own, I guess.